# Где использовать volatile

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency

1. Когда можно использовать `volatile`, если он не обеспечивает атомарность чтения и записи как Atomic'и.
2. Мне не понятно в чем разница между `volatile` и `synchronized`, если и то и другое обеспечивает синхронизацию между кэшами ядер процессора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Модификатор `volatile` гарантирует видимость операций с полем и сохранение их последовательности. Волатильную переменную можно, например, использовать как флаг завершения работы потока:

```
public class Main {
    private static volatile boolean run = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Thread(() -> {
            long x = 0;
            while (run) {
                System.out.println(++x);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException exc) {}
            }
        }).start();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (run) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("exit".equals(line))
                run = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Без модификатора `volatile` у вас нет гарантии, что поток выводящий значения переменной `x` когда-нибудь заметит, что главный поток изменил состояние переменной `run`.

Синхронизация гарантирует видимость операций, сохранение их последовательности и атомарность.

```
public class Main {
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 1000;

    private static synchronized void transfer() {
        ++x;
        --y;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
                    transfer();
                }
            }).start();
        }

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Без модификатора `synchronized` у вас нет гарантии, что значение переменной `x` будет увеличено на столько же, на сколько уменьшено значение переменной `y`, так как порядок и продолжительность выполнения потоков непредсказуемы.

Во втором примере `volatile` не поможет. В первом может помочь использование синхронизации, но тогда на каждой итерации один из потоков будет блокировать мьютекс, а второй потом будет останавливаться, пока мьютекс не будет освобождён. Это существенно медленнее проверки состояния волатильной переменной.

Comment: то есть volatile можно использовать просто для хранения какого значения которое приходит из вне или она сама не учавствует в вычислении, только так?

Comment: Волатильное поле - это такое же поле, как и любое другое, использовать его можно как угодно. Просто без модификтора привычные операции с полем могут вести себя непривычно в многопоточной среде.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю что volatile Это такая микро synchronized

Comment: _Volatile variables is a weaker form of synchronization_ © Brian Goetz

Answer (score 0):

Вам почти правильно ответили. Только оптимизации несколько другого рода. Дело в том, что переменная может быть закеширована для более быстрого доступа. Вариантов куча где именно. Например она может быть закеширована для каждого процессора отдельно, может быть закеширована в потоке, в принципе это зависит от того, какая реализация JVM используется.

Volatile просто запрещает подобное кэширование.

Теперь как его использовать. Volatile работает быстрее, потому что никаких блокировок не происходит. В этом его преимущество перед synchronized.

Работа со ссылками атомарна, поэтому там в теории это может быть актуальным.

А так да, конструкция относительно редкая, обычно при многопоточности используется что-то специфическое, дабы упростить работу с ней.

**UPD.**
Там "на заборах" пишут, что long и double которые не обязательно атомарные, становятся атомарными с volatile. Но официального подтверждения я этому не нашел, если у кого то есть точная информация по этому поводу, будет круто

Comment: volatile запрещает кэширование - насколько я знаю это не так, если запрещать кэширование значит уменшить производительность.

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile возможно вы и правы. Там не говорится, что значение не будет кэшироваться, лишь говорится что значение всегда будет актуальным. А как оно будет реализовано, дело уже конкретной JVM

Comment: Плюс да, забываю упомянуть про reordering и happened before. А это обычно и связяано с многопоточностью. В общем почитайте про Java Memory model, из таких ресурсов будет намного больше точной инфомрациии, чем из каких нибудь статеек или ответов.

Comment: Все что я написал это лишь моя интерпретация Java Memory Model, причем по памяти ) Поэтому наверное поизучайте именно оригинал, а то будет как спорченый телефон, вне зависимости от того, кто напишет вам ответ, разве что можно разжевать на булочках и пирожках.

Comment: не стоит писать если нет уверенности в этом, другие кто не понимает реально воспримет за данность, особенно про запрет на кеширование, слишком заманичиво легкое понимание